# Day.js countdown timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need to create a simple timer that is counting from 10 minutes down and after 10 minuets it will chnage `isValid` from `true` to `false`. But I was ask to do this with Day.js. This is getting a bit tricky. I am checking Day.js docs but I am faling to get this working.
This is waht i got, nut much and not even close to get this working properly:

```js
const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0);
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
const tokenTTL = 10;
// let difference;
const now = dayjs().second();
// const nowFormat = dayjs().format("hh:mm:ss");
const addTime = dayjs().add(tokenTTL, "minute");
const timeTo = addTime.subtract(now).minute();

useEffect(() => {
    // const actualTime = new Date();
    // const target = new Date(
    //   actualTime.setMinutes(actualTime.getMinutes() + tokenTTL)
    // );

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(now);
        console.log("TT", timeTo);
        console.log("add", addTime.format("mm:ss"));
        console.log("nf", dayjs().second());
        console.log(TimeHelper.getCurrentDateTime());

        setMinutes(dayjs().minute());
        setSeconds(dayjs().second());
        // const now = new Date();
        // difference = target.getTime() - now.getTime();
        // let m: string | number = Math.floor(
        //   (difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)
        // );
        // m = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
        // setMinutes(m as number);
        // let s: string | number = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        // s = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;
        // setSeconds(s as number);
        // if (difference === 0) {
        //   isValid(false);
        // }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);

return (
    <p className="Timer">
        <span className="minutes">{minutes}</span>
        <span className="divider">:</span>
        <span className="seconds">{seconds}</span>
    </p>
);
```

As you can see, with some basic stuff that tehy provide I do get minutes and seconds using `setMinutes(dayjs().minute());` and `setSeconds(dayjs().second());` also i was able to add 10 minutes to my current time that I am getting from `const now = dayjs().second();` `const addTime = dayjs().add(tokenTTL, "minute");` but this is all i can get from this. I am strugling to get this properly worknig and counting down from 10 minutes.

Is this even posible to get this done with Day.js?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/baf3dcvt/

Comment: thanks. this was exrem helpful. This is not using Day.js but it is a simple as it can be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my timer component:

```
    import React,{ useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function Timer() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    let duration = 2;
    let endTime = new Date();
    endTime.setMinutes(endTime.getMinutes() + duration);
    let min = duration;
    let sec = 0;
    
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      sec--;
      if (sec === -1) {
        sec = 59;
        min--;
      }
      let newValue=<><span className="minutes">{formatNumber(min)}</span>
      <span className="divider">:</span>
      <span className="seconds">{formatNumber(sec)}</span></>
      if ((min === 0) && (sec === 0)) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      setTime(newValue);      
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  let formatNumber=(num)=>{
    return num.toLocaleString("en-US", {
      minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
      useGrouping: false
    });
  }
  return <p className="Timer">{time}</p>;
}
```

The demo URL:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cagrm7?file=src%2FTimer.js

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple Typescript component for dayjs:

```js
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from "dayjs";
import duration from "dayjs/plugin/duration";
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";

dayjs.extend(duration);

interface CountdownProps {
  endTime: Dayjs;
}

export const Countdown: React.FC<CountdownProps> = ({
  endTime,
}) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState<string>();

  useMemo(() => {
    var currentTime = dayjs();
    var diffTime = endTime.unix() - currentTime.unix();
    
    var duration = dayjs.duration(diffTime * 1000, "milliseconds");
    var interval = 1000;
    const twoDP = (n: number) => (n > 9 ? n : "0" + n);

    setInterval(function () {
      duration = dayjs.duration(
        duration.asMilliseconds() - interval,
        "milliseconds"
      );
      let timestamp = `${
        duration.days() && duration.days() + "d "
      }${duration.hours()}h ${twoDP(duration.minutes())}m ${twoDP(
        duration.seconds()
      )}s`;
      setTime(timestamp);
    }, interval);
  }, [endTime]);
  return <>{time}</>;
};
```